Is there a textbook series that uses semantic naming for mathematical theorems?
One of my biggest pet peeves with traditional mathematical pedagogy is the ubiquity of non-semantic names (naming things after people being the typical offense...), even when an appropriate semantic identifier of similar length is available.  For example, it costs basically nothing to say "frequency decomposition" instead of "Fourier transform," or "lossless compression theorem" instead of "Shannon theorem."
Even when no such semantic identifier has been established as "canonical," it is often not hard to imagine such names for common mathematical concepts.  Some examples:

L'hopital's rule: "slope ratio rule"
Riemann integral: "domain integral"
Lebesgue integral: "codomain integral"
Kalman filter: "covariance filter"
Normal distribution: "central limit distribution"

Of course, short semantic names for complicated concepts are not perfect - but I think, all else being equal, imperfect semantic labels are still a lot better than arbitrary or meaningless labels.
Does anyone know of any modern mathematical textbooks that strongly prefer semantic names to non-semantic names?  Is this something that we should ever expect to improve, or has the use of arbitrary identifiers become a sufficiently-ingrained part of mathematical culture that I should just give up hope on it ever being done differently?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is an interesting question. But apart from the obvious fact that semantic naming as suggested is not doable in any foreseeable time since naming things after their inventors is deeply ingrained into the culture of mathematics, I will argue that it isn't an improvement either, thus answering the subquestion Is this something that we should ever expect to improve in the negative.
I think my claim is best explained by an example. Let's say we rename the Sylow theorems from finite group theory as follows. First of all, we need to rename "Sylow subgroup" to "maximal $p$-subgroup", and then perhaps:

1st Sylow Theorem $\to$ "Existence theorem for maximal $p$-subgroups in finite groups"
2nd Sylow Theorem $\to$ "Conjugacy theorem about maximal $p$-subgroups in finite groups"
3rd Sylow Theorem $\to$ "Divisibility relations for the number of maximal $p$-subgroups in finite groups"

We may come up with different names, but probably nothing will be as short and memorable as "$n$th Sylow Theorem". It is a label that enables us to access the content of these theorems very quickly. It doesn't really matter how to choose that label, as long as it has some connection to the subject, and it is human-friendly. For example, tags on the stacks project are perfect for a computer, but not for a human mind. Of course, the string "1st Sylow Theorem" does not tell us anything about the content of the theorem, but our brain does not parse it as a string, character by character. It is used as a label to look up a theorem in our memory. And here the label is connected to the theorem because it mentions the mathematician who invented this important theorem. The alternative names that I suggested above are far too long for being an efficient label.
Notice that, but this is a special case here, the three labels for the Sylow Theorems are so similar that our brain can easily capture them in one group. Of course, we could achieve the same by naming the theorems "1st Theorem about maximal $p$-subgroups" etc., but again I will argue that this is too long to be a good label.
Another problem is that every time we need to find a semantic name. I really had to think a lot about my suggestion for the 3rd Sylow theorem above. At first, this doesn't sound like a disadvantage. After all, as you have written in the comments, we use semantic names all the time in computer science and also use resources to find good names, because we benefit from them. Even though the analogy between mathematics and computer science is strong, I would say it does not apply here. Names for functions and modules in code need to be semantic and descriptive, because they shall explain concisely what the code does, without the need to read all of the code. Parsing the content of a mathematical theorem is much easier - not so much the proof of course, which does correspond to a program under the Curry-Howard correspondence. Here, a semantic name could be a "slogan" of the proof, or just the name of the main method being used. In the example above, I am therefore saying that "Every finite group has a $p$-Sylow subgroup for every divisor $p$ of its order" is easy to parse, hence we do not necessarily need a semantic name for this statement. But as mentioned, a label or tag will be useful (1st Sylow Theorem).
But now comes the biggest problem, the issue with missing scalability. Let's imagine for the moment in a parallel universe Sylow had found a 4th theorem, which also talks about divisibility relations for the number of maximal $p$-subgroups in finite groups. But it is a new result, substantially different from the 3rd theorem. Now we will run into a big problem, namely we need to find a new semantic name for this result and make sure that it is different from the name of the 3rd theorem, but still talks about the same topic without sounding too similar. In any case, it is just so much simpler with our (current) naming scheme, it will just be the 4th Sylow Theorem and that's it.
This is yet another instance where the analogy to computer science breaks. In mathematics, we all develop in one giant codebase, so to speak. Hence, every name will be the in the global scope. Nothing like that happens in software development. This is why naming collisions in mathematics are much more likely if the names are too general.
This is also why your suggestion to use "codomain integral" for the Lebesgue integral is flawed. There are several other integrals that could also be called like that, so we will need to be more specific with our names to avoid naming collisions.
Let's look at a different example, the notion of a Hausdorff space. Small digression, but I find it quite funny that I forgot for a moment that Hausdorff refers to the name of a mathematician (even though, of course, I know that when I think about the origin of this word). When we use the term "Hausdorff" everyday, it becomes a normal word just like "tree". But anyway... how do we then call a space in which every two points can be separated by two disjoint open subsets? Maybe we call it a point-separable space, but apart from being easy to confuse with a separable space this name name could arguably also go to $T_0$- and $T_1$-spaces. Maybe we can use the fact that a topological space is Hausdorff if and only if limits of nets are unique if they exist, but I don't think we will find such a concise name as "Hausdorff space", well or $T_2$-space. The separation axioms $T_n$ are also non-semantic names, and here I have to admit that I often forget the meaning of some of them, but this is just because the labels are so similar, short, and quite many. The meaning of the term "normal Hausdorff space" is much more easy to remember than "$T_4$-space", at least for my brain. Here, "normal" is also not semantic either (why is exactly this property being called normal?), but arguably much easier to write and talk about than "closed-subset-separable space".
Some other terms where I find it hard to find practical semantic names and I highly doubt that we will profit from them anyway:

Eisenstein polynomial (polynomial with prime element condition?)
Grothendieck category (convenient abelian category?)
Cauchy's Theorem for groups (existence theorem for elements of order $p$?)
Leibniz formula for determinants (alternating sum-product formula for determinants?)
Lie group (smooth group? Again one of these words where I forgot that they are names.)
Lie algebra (smooth algebra means something else, maybe bracketed algebra? We lose the connection to smooth groups then.)
Brouwer's fixed point theorem (we cannot just name it fixed point theorem because of many others, then probably just fixed point theorem for compact metric spaces?)
Fréchet derivative (yeah we could just speak of derivative, but then have a collision with other derivatives, also named after their inventors to provide an easy distinction)

I could go on forever. Notice that the semantic name is always longer and hence not so easy to memorize.

I have seen people conversing using tags for theorems and arxiv doi for papers (in speech), it's truly amazing.

@MartinBrandenburg Don't worry :-) Thanks for the tip, I will try to follow it.

This is a really good reply.  I guess my response is that I think there is more middle ground here than this post represents - the mathematical namespace isn’t truly global, and we can freely mix meaningful signifiers with arbitrary extensions when disambiguating collisions (I think “the first maximal p-subgroup theorem” is definitely an improvement, in the abstract, over “the first Sylow theorem.”
